# Device Control Threading Data Received Event Error

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, serial-port, task

My coworkers and I have spent a few days searching for a solution and most responses say to get rid of unnecessary threads. Here's the situation.

I am controlling up to 1-55 devices (depending on user needs). I must initialize every device at approximately the same time. I do this by making a `Task` for each call to `InitializeDevice(deviceNumber)` which will start the initialization of each device and then poll the device until done.

The `SerialPort.Write()` override function is `lock`ed so that only one device can write at a time, so that is not my issue (thoroughly tested). When I create tasks for 3 devices, I'm fine. When I create tasks for 4 devices, my serial port stops working correctly (though it works on my coworkers who has 6 cores compared to my 4 cores). The `DataReceived` event ceases to be trigger for a short while, as explained below.

```
Write(command1); // Attempt 1, task 1 fails to get a response when responseTimeout.WaitOne(50) times out
Write(command1); // Attempt 2, task 1 fails to get a response due to 50ms timeout
Write(command1); // Attempt 3, task 1 fails to get a response due to 50ms timeout
Write(command1); // Attempt 4, task 1 fails to get a response due to 50ms timeout
Write(command1); // Attempt 5, task 1 fails to get a response due to 50ms timeout
DataReceived event is triggered and at this point BytesToWrite contains all the data that has been accumulated.
After this initial DataReceived event delay, everything proceeds as expected. (this is one of the biggest reasons that I believe that it is either the creation or starting of the `Task`s that breaks the port)
```

We can't get rid of the tasks because it's important to our application to start at seemingly the same time.

To test if creating the `Task`s was the bottleneck, we tried creating all the `Task`s then starting them at the same time, but that didn't work either, which makes it seem like starting the threads is the problem.
To test if starting the `Task`s was the issue, we set a breakpoint in `InitializeDevice(deviceNumber)` and it was hit by all 4 `Task`s that we had made **before** the `SerialPort.Write()` function is ever called. Since all 4 had been created, started and were running before any `Write`s were made, you would think that the `Task`s couldn't be the bottleneck.
When I bumped the `responseTimeout.WaitOne(time)` from `50` to `1000` the `Write`s were all successful, though the delays between the `Write` and when `DataReceived` was triggered were as follows: 990ms, 6ms, 15ms, 15ms, 16ms, etc. The average time for responses was about 15ms.
We connected a logic analyzer with and without `Task`s being used, and the response time was approximately 5ms invariably, so it isn't like we are losing responses, just that the event isn't triggering in a reasonable time.
We have tried setting `DataReceived` as highest priority and the initialization `Task`s as lowest to no avail.

Everything points towards this being a problem with `Task`s or thread creation taking processor speed and preventing `DataReceived` from triggering in a reasonable amount of time. We can't just wait indefinitely for a response, and we have to simultaneously start all devices. We have run out of solutions at this point.

---

Example Code

```
public class DeviceControl
{
    private static void Initialize_AllDevices(CustomSerialPort port, List<Device> devices)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++)
        {
            DeviceNumber deviceNumber = i;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => Initialize_SingleDevice(port, devices, deviceNumber));
        }
    }

    private static void Initialize_SingleDevice(CustomSerialPort port, List<Device> devices, int deviceNumber)
    {
        List<byte> command = devices[deviceNumber].CreateCommand();
        port.Write(command);
    }
}

public class CustomSerialPort : SerialPort
{
    private AutoResetEvent _responseTimeout;

    public CustomSerialPort()
    {
        DataReceived += Read;
        _responseTimeout = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }

    private void Read(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // This is what is not reached until Task creation is complete.
        // Parse response
        if (ReadSuccessful())
        {
            _responseTimeout.Set();
        }
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        lock (new object())
        {
            Write(command.ToArray(), 0, command.Count);

            // Wait until response timeout is hit or response is received.
            _responseTimeout.Reset();
            if (!_responseTimeout.WaitOne(50))
            {
                // uh oh
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are these devices are sharing the one serial port control? or are they just sharing the one received event?

Comment: Please post the _actual code_ rather than just talk about it.  This will help us help you.  [mcve].  Good luck!

Comment: Actual code (as much as I can really post due to IP), has been included. However, the problem is only reproducible if you have multiple devices operating at a million baud and have limited cores.